# How can I drag the slider to the end and verify text box has value 20

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

Here is the html snippets:

```
<html><head><title>Javascript Slider Control - Example</title>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example_files/slider.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="example_files/addanevent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example_files/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example_files/slider-setup.js"></script></head><body>

Slider 1:
<div class="slider" id="slider01">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <img style="left: 207px;" src="example_files/knob.png" height="15" width="31">
</div>
Box 1:
<input id="output1">
<hr>

</body></html>
```

I want to drag the slider till the end and want to check whether the outbox box has the value of 20 or not.I searched for many things. Gone through many topics but could not get my answer. I didn't understand how can I set values for xoffset and yoffset. I just entered the value randomly and checked. Is there any procedure of getting the value of offsets.

Here is my code:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  driver.get(url)
  slider =  driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='slider01']")
  def verify_drag_drop_till_end
    driver.action.drag_and_drop_by(slider,120,0).perform
    sleep 1
    output_box = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='output1']")
    puts output_box[:value]
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Without all the code for the page, I can't test it on your specific page but I found a jQueryUI slider example page at https://jqueryui.com/slider/. There is a slider handle defined there and when I slid it, it worked. From the HTML, it looks like you are grabbing the slider (the control itself) and not the handle (knob). Have you tried grabbing the knob `IMG` tag and sliding it?

The x and y offsets are in px so 120 seems like a reasonable value but it will vary depending on the size of your slider.

As a side note, I would suggest that when you are locating an element by id that you find it using find element by id instead of by XPath. Finding things by XPath is very slow (in comparison) and not necessary when locating an element like this.